# Get Users with meta query filtering on foreach loop from ACF Users field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to work out why my loop isn't working.

I'm wanting to loop through all users on the site and then use a meta query to display only the users that have the current users name in a user field. Essentially like if someone added you as a friend/connection, but you didn't add them. So the the current user can see who's added them to their connections.

I'm using an ACF user field to do this.

The code i'm using that isn't working is below:

```
<div class="connectedtoyou usersloop teamloop" style="margin-top:40px!important;margin-bottom:40px!important;display:none!important;">
<hr>
<div class="users">
<h3 class="center centered">Users connected to you</h3>
<?php 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
//$connect_user = 'user_'.$current_user->ID;
//$connect_field = get_field('user_follows');

$args = array(
        //'role' => 'subscriber',  
        'orderby' => 'display_name',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_63d0017ab088f',
                'value' => $current_user->ID,
                'compare' => '=='
            )
         )
        );
$users = get_users($args);
if( $users ): ?>
<div class="row isotope">
    <?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
    <div class="col fade-up item">
            <div class="item-container"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->id ); ?>" style="text-decoration:none!important;">
                <?php if ('health' == get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mepr_select_ident', true)) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/D4HGN_Logo_2.png" alt="Health">
                <?php } elseif ('design' == get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mepr_select_ident', true)) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/D4HGN_Logo_1.png" alt="Design">
                <?php } elseif ('research' == get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mepr_select_ident', true)) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/D4HGN_Logo_3.png" alt="Research">
                <?php } elseif ('global' == get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mepr_select_ident', true)) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/D4HGN_Logo_4.png" alt="Global">
                <?php } elseif ('network' == get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mepr_select_ident', true)) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/D4HGN_Logo_5.png" alt="Network">
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <h4 class="darkgrey"><?php echo esc_html( $user->first_name ); ?> <?php echo esc_html( $user->last_name ); ?></h4>
            </a></div>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<p>No users are connected to you. <a href="https://d4hgn.com/network/network-users/">Click here to see who's on the network</a>.</p>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I work this out?

Comment: The bits inside the loop are not problematic. As they work elsewhere. It associates to a Memberpress form that has certain selections associated with logos (clients request). The issue is definitely within the foreach loop/meta query. But I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: The User field allows to store one or multiple users; since you mentioned a "friendship" type of connection here, I am assuming you are allowing multiple values, and not just one? Have you check in the database, _how_ ACF actually stores this? (With repeater fields they insert an index into the actual key name used in the meta data table, I could imagine that with the User field type, they do something similar.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
  //'role' => 'subscriber',  
  'orderby' => 'display_name',
  'order'   => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'user_follows',
      'value' => $current_user->ID,
      'compare' => '='
    )
  )
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Comment: Found the problem... It was this:

`'value' => '"'.$current_user->ID.'"'`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this:

`'value' => '"'.$current_user->ID.'"'`

Which I hadn't thought of.

Thanks for all your help with this :)